# What is the process of decoding a SAML request?

Tags: decode, saml-2.0

I am trying to decode a SAML request in VBA. I know the request is encoded so I URL decode it first and then base64 decode it but this didn't decode the request.

Can you please suggest what is the process of decoding a SAML request as in deflating, url decoding, etc? Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated.

Please note: I am referring to SAML request and not SAML response. SAML response works fine when I URL decode it and after that base64 decode it.

Comment: It depends on the binding in use: do you receive the request in a query parameter or in a post parameter?

Comment: The request is in a query parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the request is in a query parameter, it is (most likely) using the HTTP Redirect binding. It uses compression to shorten the URL. To decode it, you need to:

1. URL-decode the query string data.
2. Base64-decode the data.
3. Un-Deflate (the deflate compression algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know if there is a built in function for deflate compression algorithm in VBA? In C#/other languages, there are libraries but I am creating a macro which sorts the data and then decodes & decompresses (using deflate algorithm) the saml requests so have to use VBA. Any link/pointers will be much appreciated.